# Remotely edit winrm conf file

Tags: powershell, winrm

Im trying to edit the winrm conf file on remote computer.  I dont have the possibility to use GPO edit so i must find another way.
I've tried to set the configurations that i need by using the "winrm set winrm/config/winrs"  command,  which works fine locally but fails remotely 
 i use: "Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock { COMMAND }" 
  I guess,  changing winrm conf while using winrm is quite problematic.

Please do you have some other suggestion?

Comment: `I've tried to set the configurations that i need by using the "winrm set winrm/config/winrs" command, which works fine locally but fails remotely` And your error message/failure would be...?

Comment: just "WSManFault    message  = access is denied ".  Im Administrator on both servers

Comment: Maybe use PSEXEC from the Sysinternal tools? That allows you to execute commands remotely, and doesn't require WinRM.